# Is reconstruction of pen strokes from real life video on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

[This question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/reconstruction-drawing-sequence-from-video) is about recovering the series of movements that an artist made with a pencil. Can this fit into the scope of our Computer Graphics site?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. It's an interesting application of graphics algorithms, and certainly the kind of thing a working graphics programmer or researcher might want to do.

Comment: But it is stated that 'Computer Vision' is not on topic for the computer-graphics stack-exchange. And isn't the question in question far more computer vision than computer graphics?